# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' AFTER mysql-workbench install

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I know sort of this question is asked before. But I've tried almost everything.

I don't have that .sock file in /var/run/mysqld as in /var/run/mysql folder

MySQL seems to be running:

```
mysql    25359  5.0  0.6 394008 49628 ?        Ssl  22:09   0:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

This all seem to have happend after installing mysql-workbench for Linux.

I don't want to lose my databases.

**EDIT**

Noticed that when running: `ps aux | grep -i mysql` the id is changing every time.

Comment: check my.ini/my.cnf and see where mysql got told to put the socket file, and remember that the setting can also be overridden at the command line.

Comment: look in the file /etc/my.cnf or /etc/mysqld/my.cnf and search for socket and you find like this "socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"

Comment: Check the open file descriptors `lsof -p 25359` and ensure it uses the `.sock` file and not TCP to bind and listen.

Comment: socket  = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock. But there is no such file in there.

Comment: lsof -p 25359 gives error: lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /root/.gvfs Output information may be incomplete.

Comment: Have you try to connect to the IP # mysql -h IP -u root -p

Comment: @BerndBuffen thank you for helping. Just tried it with: mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p. Result: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111). Also tried: mysql -h localhost -u root -p. Result: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2).

Comment: i seems so that the mysql is not propper running. Test the -protocol=tcp in the mysql command

Comment: If you have install nmap you can try this with localhost/ 127.0.0.1 to see if someone listen

#map localhost -p 3306

Starting Nmap 5.20 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-09-14 22:56 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000092s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE
3306/tcp open  mysql

Comment: Done that my result is: Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000029s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
3306/tcp closed mysql. Mine seems closed what does that mean?

Comment: Did you run the mysql service as sudo? What was the procedure you used for starting it? Do you use supervisord to keep MySQL process alive in case of crash?

Comment: @N.B. Well I installed it months ago with **sudo apt-get install mysql-server**. But it crashed yesterday since I installed mysql-workbench for making database models (already removed it btw). I don't know about supervisord, I don't think I use it. It's about my local mysql-server.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by uninstalling first with these commands:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/265685/how-to-reinstall-mysql

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Then I did:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

This gave me an error: **mysql-server : Depends: mysql-community-server**

Finally found this answer here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/598311/unable-to-reinstall-mysql-on-ubuntu/598348#598348?newreg=2b582d1e674c4300841cde06b892e7ef

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-apt-config && sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

That magically fixed everything. Also the databases are still there.